# Should I buy a used camera with a scratched anti-aliasing filter?

Tags: used-equipment, scratches

I'm considering buying a friend's old camera, low shutter count, around 13,500. But it has a scratch on the anti-aliasing filter. However I see that these parts are easily available online. Should I buy it for a low price and replace the filter myself?

From some videos it seems easy and doable as it's just a glass slide. But what are your opinions?

There is no visible impact on image quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part which has the scratch is UV and IR blocking glass - yes, it is quite easy to replace it in many cameras.

However, you should be attentive during disassembly and assembly - do not neglect the warnings which tutorials give.

There is no reason to change it if you see no impact on quality. You probably will if you close the aperture down to F22 or F32.

Comment: Thank you!
From your answer I gather that UV and IR harm the sensor?

Out of curiosity, I've read some new DSLRS lack it, like the Nikon D3300. So how does it work that some cameras have one and others don't?

Comment: @user2440943: UV and IR harm colour reproduction, not the sensor itself. Yes, it is possible that some sensor have IR cut filter built in without ability to interchange it (no matter that I haven't heard of such to the moment). However, I cannot find any mention of that D3300 is one of those. 

You migh probably talk about AA filter - completely another story.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 

The 3300 is indeed one of those.

Comment: Do you think I can use another APS-C low pass filter for my camera? Given the relatively constant sensor size, it shouldn't be a problem, am I right?

Comment: You need the correct part made for the camera into which it is installed. Different cameras use different thicknesses and how wide or narrow the light is diffused will vary based upon the pixel pitch of the sensor as well as the design decisions of the manufacturer.

Comment: @user2440943: if there was no AA filter initially, why would you need one? Your questions are somewhat confusing.

Comment: @PinhollowEuri- Hello, I never said that. I was just informing you that the D3300 actually doesn't have one, since you said you couldn't find any information on the matter. The camera I have purchased is a completely different. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: @MichaelClark- Thank you very much, that's the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @user2440943: "Thanks for your response! The 3300 is indeed one of those" : D3300 definitely lacks AA filter (and completely intentinally so) and AA filter (often built onto the sensor) is NOT hot mirror (UV/IR filter, almost never built onto the sensor even in cheap cameras). AA filter is blurring filter which prevents certain artifacts, it is completely different matter.